# SQL: Get all dates between two dates with shift

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that content the column "startbooking" and "endbooking"
I have other that content the shift:

```
id |start  |end
M  | 06:00 |14:00
T  | 14:00 |20:00
N  | 20:00 |06:00
```

so, i need to get all dates between startbooking and endbooking with the shifts

example:

```
startbooking: 01/05/2015 12:00  endbooking: 02/05/2015 16:00
```

result:

```
01/05/2015 |M
01/05/2015 |T
01/05/2015 |N
02/05/2015 |M
02/05/2015 |T
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you any code showing your attempt to solve this yourself?

Comment: Where is the `Date` datatype column?

Comment: i have nothing, i was trying but only get the dates between.

Comment: startbooking and endbooking are date columns

Comment: @YainaVillafañes Please read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Full code examples, data structures etc are required to fully understand your query, simply mentioning that another column exists somewhere doesn't really help. You also say "i have nothing" but then say "i was trying but only get..." so you do have something, please provide that. Thanks.

Comment: @GandRalph ok, sorry, was because i wanted a new solution without my base... I was trying 

`WITH DateRange(DateData) AS ( 
SELECT startbookingdate as Date from [bookings] where idbookingcode=20 
UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(d,1,DateData) 
FROM DateRange 
WHERE DateData < (select endbookingdate as Date from [bookings] where idbookingcode=20) 
) SELECT DateData FROM DateRange`

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you will need *recursive* `cte` with `cross` join :

```
with t as (
     select startdt, enddt
     from table
     union all
     select dateadd(day, 1, startdt), enddt
     from t
     where startdt < enddt
)

select t.startdt, sft.id
from t cross join (select distinct id from shifttable) sft
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Here is a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6fe325/7).